# How to use created "net" neural network object for prediction?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series, prediction

I used **ntstool** to create NAR (nonlinear Autoregressive) net object, by training on a 1x1247 input vector. (daily stock price for 6 years)
I have finished all the steps and saved the resulting net object to workspace.

Now I am clueless on how to use this object to predict the y(t) for example t = 2000, (I trained the model for t = 1:1247)

In some other threads, people recommended to use sim(net, t) function - however this will give me the same result for any value of t. (same with net(t) function)

Comment: @Marc I think the train data is not the problem, because all the example inputs are in the same format.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the specific neural net commands, but I think you are approaching this problem in the wrong way. Typically you want to model the evolution in time. You do this by specifying a certain window, say 3 months.

What you are training now is a single input vector, which has no information about evolution in time. The reason you always get the same prediction is because you only used a single point for training (even though it is 1247 dimensional, it is still 1 point).

You probably want to make input vectors of this nature (for simplicity, assume you are working with months):

```
[month1 month2; month2 month 3; month3 month4]
```

This example contains 2 training points with the evolution of 3 months. Note that they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Network
After the network is trained and validated, the network object can be used to calculate the network response to any input. For example, if you want to find the network response to the fifth input vector in the building data set, you can use the following
a = net(houseInputs(:,5))
a =
  34.3922
If you try this command, your output might be different, depending on the state of your random number generator when the network was initialized. Below, the network object is called to calculate the outputs for a concurrent set of all the input vectors in the housing data set. This is the batch mode form of simulation, in which all the input vectors are placed in one matrix. This is much more efficient than presenting the vectors one at a time.
a = net(houseInputs);
Each time a neural network is trained, can result in a different solution due to different initial weight and bias values and different divisions of data into training, validation, and test sets. As a result, different neural networks trained on the same problem can give different outputs for the same input. To ensure that a neural network of good accuracy has been found, retrain several times.
There are several other techniques for improving upon initial solutions if higher accuracy is desired. For more information, see Improve Neural Network Generalization and Avoid Overfitting.
strong text